# How to open links using a chrome app? (Similar to how Android prompts you on what app you want to use to handle certain URLs)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome app which displays data pulled from website A.

If a user has the app installed, and is on website A, how can I make the chrome app detect that the user is on website A and then prompt the user to open website A in the chrome app?

I'm trying to mimic how Android does this if you try to open a Google Play Store URL for example.

Thanks in advance,
Dimitry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app needs to define a [webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) (part of permissions) in the [manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) file. You might use the blocking response to then handle all the stuff yourself.